# DISTINCT vs CASE statements in Postgresql sums

Tags: postgresql

I have an SQL query that uses DISTINCT to sum up the costs of an category of items that can be grouped as Sets (each set = 1 and is counted once) or Whole using an `inventory_type` attribute. The query below sums up these attributes fairly well for the most part:

```
(sum(distinct product_working_value_SET)+sum(product_working_value_WHOLE)) working_cost_category

  FROM (select
      case inventory_type when 'set' then product_working_value else 0 end as product_working_value_SET,
      case inventory_type when 'whole' then product_working_value else 0 end as product_working_value_WHOLE
  )
```

The problem emerges when I have two different sets with the same cost; the query does not recognize it as distinct and skips over it, and giving an inaccurate sum. The only solid distinctions I could use would be `product_name` or `product_id`; Sets would be far more likely to have distinct naming in this scenario. Can I rework this to account for this level of specificity?

Here's an example category dataset, with reported and expected values (again, sets are meant to be counted as one each):

```
        Name    Inventory Type  Working Cost $
    Blue & Gold King Bed Set    Set $480.00
    Blue & Gold King Bed Set    Set $480.00
    Floral Bed Set  Set $240.00
    King Blue and White Floral Bed Set  Set $240.00
    King Blue and White Floral Bed Set  Set $240.00
    King Orange Comforter Set   Set $168.00 <<< same price
    King Orange Comforter Set   Set $168.00
    King Orange Comforter Set   Set $168.00
    King Orange Comforter Set   Set $168.00
    King Orange Comforter Set   Set $168.00
    King Orange Comforter Set   Set $168.00
    Red Queen Set   Set $60.00
    Red Queen Set   Set $60.00
    Red Queen Set   Set $60.00
    White King Comforter Set    Set $168.00 <<< same price coincidentally again
    White King Comforter Set    Set $168.00
    White King Comforter Set    Set $168.00
    White King Comforter Set    Set $168.00
    White King Comforter Set    Set $168.00

working_cost_category: reported:          $990.00
                       audit calculation: $1158 (168 missing)
```

Comment: Add some sample data and expected results to describe the issue you are facing.

Comment: The full thing's a bit of a monster, so I'm trying to keep this as concise and readable as possible. I'll try.

Comment: You probably might rework your question: what are you trying to sum up? Your data sample suggests that what you name "product_name" is the unique key where different instances may be distinguished by what seems to be labeled "Tag #" in the data (not mentioned in the initial query). And the "product_working_value_WHOLE" that is shown with your initial query seems to come out of hot air, somehow? Clearly stating what you want to achieve will help others to give helpful answers.

Comment: product_working_value_WHOLE is defined in the code block in the FROM SELECT() section. In avoiding counting duplicate sets, DISTINCT is skipping unique sets that are priced the same, and I want to correct this.

Comment: I see, you updated after my comment. Nevertheless, creating 2 columns in a sub query just to add them in the outer query is strange at best. Usually this indicates your sub query (not shown) can be significantly improved or there is more to the story than you did tell.